# MYSQL displaying record older than the current date based on specific format

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing date in database using this format. `Tue 27 Mar, 2018` which is format of `'D d M, Y'`. How can I display records from the database which are older than the current date using specific date format?

I have created this function first to see if it correctly finds expired records. However, it does not work.

```
$dateToday = DateTime::createFromFormat('D d M, Y', date(' D d M, Y'));

$query = "SELECT * FROM offer WHERE date < '$dateToday' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row['date'];
}
```

Comment: Are you using varchar for date?

Answer (score 0):

Storing temporal information(DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP etc) as plain text is considered a major design flaw because mysql will never know the nature of this data hence no possibility of using powerful search and indexing algorithms meant for these datatypes.

To compare dates mysql can use only so even if a string like `Sun 01 April, 2018` might look like a valid date to you but for mysql it's just a regular string like `hello`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM offer WHERE date < 'Sun 01 Apr, 2018' LIMIT 1";
```

From mysql's POV the above comparison using is simply a **regular string comparison and NOT date comparison** coz it won't treat them as dates so '10 Apr' might be judged smaller than *'10 Jan'* cause 10 cancels out and *'A'* comes before *'J'*. What you need is convert these strings to an **actual date instance**

But if you closely you will realize `$dateToday` isn't even a string but a PHP datetime object you cannot use it directly in mysql query (mysql doesn't know anything about PHP).So you would need to convert it to a string using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) also note that the placeholders('d','M','Y' etc) are a bit different in mysql than those used in PHP ,find the full list [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
$dateToday = DateTime::createFromFormat('D d M, Y', date(' D d M, Y'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = "SELECT * FROM offer WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%a %d %b, %Y') < STR_TO_DATE('$dateToday','%a %d %b, %Y') LIMIT 1";
```

The above correction will fix your issue.